# Append Memo Lines From A Text File In Lua

Tags: cmd, lua, wmic

I use cmd command to get my RAM info using lua script:

```
cmd = 'wmic MEMORYCHIP get BankLabel, Capacity, DeviceLocator,  MemoryType, TypeDetail, Speed,Tag >'..path..'MyRAMDetail.txt'
os.execute(cmd)
```

That code will generate a file:MyRamDetail.txt on my local disk. It contains text something like this when open via notepad:

```
BankLabel  Capacity    DeviceLocator   MemoryType  Speed  Tag                TypeDetail  
BANK 0     8589934592  ChannelA-DIMM0  0           1333   Physical Memory 0  128
```

But when I append that all text to a memo using Lua script or print it, it shows:

```
??B
```

I am using this Lua script to add lines to the memo:

```
 local open = io.open

 function read_file(fpath)
  local file = open(fpath, "rb")
  if not file then return nil end
  local content = file:read "*a"
  file:close()
  return content
 end

 local path = 'C:\\'
 local fileContent = read_file(path..'MyRAMDetail.txt')
 -- print (fileContent) check it
 memo1.Lines.Text = fileContent
```

How to print file content or append all text to the memo properly?

Regards

Comment: wmic outputs by default in UTF16-LE with a BOM, notepad++ handles this properly, your code doesn't.

Comment: Thank you for answer #LotPings. Since Lua handle string as utf-8, I need change code page using chcp 65001 and after executing my code above then change back codepage to default (my default is 850). I did with os.execute("chcp 65001").